# *ngIf daña el dropdown de cualquier menu si es un condicional de un modelo

Tags: angular, angular-directivas

resulta que estoy intentando ocultar los items de un menu dependiendo del rol de usuario

el menu  es

```
 <li *ngIf="role == 'administrator' ">
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-group"></i> <span class="nav-label">Candidatos</span> <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
                        <li><a href="#">Lista de candidatos</a></li>
                    </ul>
 </li>
```

el modelo es

```
export class User{
    constructor(
        public id: number,
        public name: string,
        public email: string,
        public password:string,
        public secondName: string,
        public token: string,
        public roles:Array<any>
    ){

    }
}
```

y el componente menu es

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { GLOBAL } from '../../providers/global';
import { AuthService } from '../../providers/auth';
import { User } from '../../models/user';

@Component({
  selector: 'menu-layout',
  templateUrl: '../../views/layout/menu.component.html',
  providers: [AuthService]
})
export class MenuComponent {
  public userModel: User;
  public message: string;
  public role:string;


  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService

  ) {
    this.userModel = new User(0, '', '', '', '', '', []);
    this.profile();
    this.role = 'abc';
  }


  profile() {
    this.authService.profile(localStorage.getItem('cvToken')).subscribe(
        response => {
            //check if the user is  logged and obtain some data
            if (response.code == 200) {
                this.userModel = response.user;
                this.role = response.user.roles[0].name;
                console.log(this.userModel);
            }
        },
        error => {
            console.log(<any>error);
        }
    );
}
}
```

donde deja de funcionar el menu es aqui

Candidatos

Lista de candidatos

lo que no funciona es el dropdow es decir 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al dar click

pero si le quito el ngIf ya funciona como se muestra en la imagen siguiente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esto ocurre porque se esta preguntando por el modelo. es decir

```
if (response.code == 200) {
                this.userModel = response.user;
                this.role = response.user.roles[0].name;//aqui el dropdown de menu ya no funciona si se pregunta por eso

                console.log(this.userModel);
            }
```

que es

```
<li *ngIf="role == 'administrator' ">
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-group"></i> <span class="nav-label">Candidatos</span> <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
                    <li><a href="#">Lista de candidatos</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
```

Esto de verdad me parece increible. Nada de esto lo he podido encontrar en internet. La solucion a esto si parece muy pesada, rara, estoy perdido con esto.

Es increíble que a nadie le halla ocurrido esto: de verdad. Y están sacando versiones de angular cada 6 meses. Acaso esto es un bug? si es un bug increible que nadie oculte el menu dependiendo del rol usuario. Este ejemplo se puede hacer con un menú de boostrap sencillo de dropdown.

Comment: Que casualidad. Nadie sabe? nadie en el planeta tierra ha manejado menu dropdown con ngIf por rol? permisos? NADIE?

Comment: ni siquiera con ngSwitchCase . bloquea el dropdown del menu. Esto parece imposible. En todo internet y ninguna respuesta. Es por  eso que no veo nada desarrollado en angular?  ni una pagina web que tenga dashboard admin y front ent. Y no entiendo porque no corregir estos bugs en ves de estar sacando versiones cada 6 meses. No entiendo esto. Ya angular me esta dando desconfianza. Requiere un gran conocimiento y exp muy avanzado. Tocaria hacerle ingenieria inversa para corregir esto o hacer una gran chambonada para corregir eso

Comment: Has probado usar https://github.com/AlexKhymenko/ngx-permissions maneja los permisos de una manera bastante practica, y permite muchas configuraciones.
PD: Tengo dropdowns con *ngIf en el interior y funcionan a la perfección, tu error puede ser porque queda sin opciones que mostrar?

Comment: gracias. probare

Comment: probandolo en angular 4 presenta muchos errores, y la guia no parece completa, por ejemplo httpClient dice que no se ha definido el provider, el metodo que es get('url') dice que la url no la reconoce.. No me sirvio, recien instalandolo en el angular 4 saca un monton de errores y buscando en internet no encontre nada

Answer (score 0):

Mi hipótesis es que sean algunas comillas que estén de mas, prueba reemplazando lo siguiente:

```
this.role = response.user.roles[0].name
```

por..

```
this.role = response.user.roles[0].name.slice(1,-1);
```